# AngularJS Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ng-view

I have a little problem. I'm working on angularjs single web application page and I'm trying to do add SockJS in angular module.

**This is my main page.**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Timeline Page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/components.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/plugins-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/light.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color" />
        <link href="css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body class="page-container-bg-solid page-md">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/sockjs-0.3.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/stomp.js"></script>
</html>
```

**This is the js code.**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services', function () {
        var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
        stompClient2 = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient2.connect({}, function (frame) {
            con = true;
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient2.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
                showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
    }]);
```

When I try this, I have this problem:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I have many pages and I want to open one socket when I open the page but it's not working. Anyone can help me?

**EDIT**
**Greeting.class**

```
public class Greeting {

    private String content;

    public Greeting(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

}
```

**GreetingController.class**

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        //Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you log the content of `greeting`?

Comment: Problem solved. It was just securty issues.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though whatever is coming back from `greeting.body` is not a *valid* json string.

Given that your error has a `<` in position 0 I would assume that html is coming back from your API instead on accident.

Comment: I tried same codes in different project with one page and it's working but when I try single web page application like this. it's not working. I don't think that's the case.

Comment: I added the classes.

Comment: @Gürsel Please log out what you get as `greeting.body` in JS. your Java views are of no use to me...

Comment: I'm just trying to connect to socket, I don't send anything yet in here.

Answer (score -1):

You must have invalid JSON response. Removing `JSON.parse` should help to avoid this error. However, you should just probably work on the server side.

You can use [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to verify the response JSON.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services', function () {
        var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
        stompClient2 = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient2.connect({}, function (frame) {
            con = true;
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient2.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
                showGreeting(greeting.body);
            });
        });
    }]);
```